# cohomology of local system

Tags: algebraic-topology, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology, simplicial-complex

Let $X_r$ be a finite simplical complex. Let $V_r$ be a sheaf which is a local system on $X_r$.
Is it true that:
$H^n(X_r,V_r$) i.e the cohomology of the sheaf $V_r$ coincide with the cohomology of the complex whose $n^{th}$ term is $\prod _{\delta}H^0(\delta,V_r)$ where $\delta$ varies over $n$ simplex of $X_r$.

It will be very helpful if someone gives a reference for this fact.

Comment: With what differential?

Comment: I don`t know. I found it here

Comment: http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~emerton/pdffiles/interpolate.pdf

Comment: It is on page 23